# Modifying chapterhead for non chapter uses

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, formatting, chapters, renewcommand

- I am currently using the `\documentclass{report}`
- I want to obtain a look similar to the following, but without affecting the index or other thing: [[Image_of_desired_chapter_style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH6tu.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH6tu.png):
  **Experiment:** (chapter number)
  **Aim:** (chapter name)
- That is, if doing raw per-element styling, then something like this:

```
\textbf{Experiment:} 1\\
\textbf{Aim:} Find the sum of ...
```

Tries:

1. renew `\chaptername` to "Experiment:"

   - input: `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Experiment:}`
   - output: 
     **Experiment: num**
     **name**
   - Comments:

     - :) No ill effects
     - :) Line break
     - :( num and name are not normal
     - :( **Aim:** is missing
2. Using titleformat & **Aim:** in 2nd argument

   - input: given below
   - output: 
     **Experiment: (num)Aim: (name)**
   - Comments:

     - :) **Aim:** appears
     - :) No ill effects
     - :( No Line break - for some reason,  `//` in the 2nd arg is not taking effect
     - :( num and name are not normal
3. Using titleformat & **Aim:** in fourth argument

   - input: given below
   - output: 
     **Experiment: (num)   Aim: (name)**
   - Comments:

     - :) **Aim:** appears
     - :( Messes up with `\tableofcontents` 
        **Contents** --> **Aim: Contents**
     - :( No Line break 
        On trying to insert `\\` before Aim: in forth argument of titleformat, a compilation error is shown at `\tableofcontents` line
     - :( num and name are not normal
4. I have read several other answers, but they being on different topic contained lots of other modifications/setup, and me being a LaTeX beginner, i was not able to extract the info relevant to me from them.

```tex
%%%%% 2nd try %%%%%
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\large\bfseries} % Formatting
{Experiment: {\thechapter} \\Aim:} % Before
{1em} % Spacing
{} % Just Before
```

```tex
%%%%% 3rd try %%%%%
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\large\bfseries} % Formatting
{Experiment: \thechapter} % Before
{1em} % Spacing
{Aim: } % Just Before
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\newcommand{\ChappreNum}{Experiment:} %  choose text before chapter number <<<<<
\newcommand{\ChappreName}{Aim:}% choose text before chapter name
    
\makeatletter   
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{20\p@}%  before chapter vertical space (pt)
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne%
        \normalsize\textbf{\ChappreNum}\space\thechapter%
        \par\nobreak%
        \fi%
        \interlinepenalty\@M%
        \normalsize \textbf{\ChappreName}\space#1\par\nobreak%
        \vskip 20\p@% after chapter vertical space (pt)
}}
\makeatother
    
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% for dummy text only

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{Find the sum}
    
    \kant[1]
    
    \chapter{Check the sum}
    
    \chapter{Approve the sum}
    
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** After follow-up question.

Using the package `titlesec` to get a similar result.

`renewcommand{\chaptername}{Experiment}` will change chapter name from "Chapter" to "Experiment"

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% for dummy text only

\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Experiment:} % change chapter name from "Chapter" to "Experiment"
\newcommand{\ChappreName}{Aim:}% choose text before chapter name

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]% {<command>}[<shape>]
{\large\bfseries}% Format
{\chaptername\space\thechapter \\ \ChappreName} % label
{1ex} %separation
{} % code before
[\vspace{-5ex}] %<after-code>

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{Find the sum}
    
    \kant[1]
    
    \chapter{Check the sum}
    
    \chapter{Approve the sum}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It worked well. Can u also share how to add a linebreak in 2nd argument of titleformat (2nd try - edited).
Also, similar to the code for number is `\thechapter` what is the code for chapter name? I tried searching, but couldnt find.

Comment: @user8395964  Please see the Update of the answer. (1) Use the the shape `block` to make the linebreak, and (2) The chapter name is `\chaptername`